# Immutable.js: how to build two data structures at once using withMutations

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Immutable.js has a nice feature, [`withMutations`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/withMutations), that lets you build a complex immutable object using a temporary mutable object to save having to create new references during the build process.

This is great for converting something like this:

```
// Bad way
var goodThing = badThing.set("something", 123);
goodThing = goodThing.set("somethingElse", 456);
goodThing = goodThing.set("anotherThing", 789);
...

// Good way
var goodThing = badThing.withMutations(function(bt) {
  bt.set("something", 123);
  bt.set("somethingElse", 456);
  bt.set("anotherThing", 789);
  ...
});
```

But what about if I want to create two objects at once?

```
// What I have now
var list1 = List();
var list2 = List();

someStuff.forEach(function(value, key) {
  list1 = list1.push(value.id);
  list2 = list2.push(key);
}); 

// The best I've come up with...
var list1 = List();
var list2 = List();

list1 = list1.withMutations(function(l1) {
  list2 = list2.withMutations(function(l2) {
    someStuff.forEach(function(value, key) {
      l1.push(value.id);
      l2.push(key);
    }); 
  });
});
```

The best thing I have thought of so far is to wrap the `withMutations` calls, but that hides the meaning of what is happening, and just looks terrible and confusing. Is there a way to pass multiple objects into a `withMutations` call? If not, what is the best way to accomplish this (unless this is it...)?

**Edit:** to be a "better" solution, it must also perform as well or better than the nested `withMutations` calls.

Comment: Why can't you just do `withMutations` on each one separately?

Comment: Because then I would need to iterate over `someStuff` twice which is probably more inefficient than just resetting the references using the old way.

Comment: Iterating over something twice doesn't make you do any more work. If you iterate twice and do some amount of work on each iteration, that's the same amount of work as iterating once and doing twice the amount of work on each iteration. The only overhead is resetting the loop counter, which is infinitesimal.

Comment: It means having to access every element in the list twice. That is work, especially if the list is large.

Comment: Accessing an element in a list is constant time (with **very** small constant, for any decent language). You really think you'll be bottlenecked by the speed of array indexing in JS?

Comment: I refer you to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wu2uS/20/) performance test of the three methods. On a list of 100,000 items, looping over every element twice takes about 20-30ms more on average than the nested `withMutation` calls. Considering that I'm doing animations, this just isn't an acceptable tradeoff. I care more about performance than style for this code. (Interestingly enough, the gap actually gets worse if you reduce the number of elements in the list to 10,000)

Comment: Anyways, I don't want to get into a war over milliseconds. I edited the question to be more clear on what I mean by "better."

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off using the functions designed for this instead of`forEach` and `push`.

```
var list1 = Immutable.List();
var list2 = Immutable.List();

var names = list.map(function(item) { return item.get("name") })
var ages = list.map(function(item) { return item.get("age") })

list1 = list1.concat(names)
list2 = list2.concat(ages)
```

In your performance test, this is faster than any of the other options. It also has the benefit of being closer to the functional programming model encouraged by Immutable.js.

http://jsfiddle.net/ecremq35/

Comment: What happens if the thing we are mapping (`someStuff` in my original example, `list` in yours) is a Map? I want to create two lists. Since `.map()` returns a similar type to the thing that was mapped, I would have to convert the two Maps, `names` and `ages` to Lists before I could concat them, correct? That is why I am currently using `.forEach()`. I ran [the your method plus conversion](http://jsfiddle.net/ecremq35/1/) and it performs worse. Is there a better way to do the conversion? I like the simplicity of your method very much.